# MSVCP110.dll is missing

Tags: c++, ruby, visual-studio-2012, sketchup

I’m writing a Sketchup ruby plugin that calls an external c++ application built using visual studios 2012 version 11.0.51106.01. Another machine that tried using the plugin gets an error about MSVCP110.dll being missing. They’ve tried installing the vcredist and it didn’t fix the problem. does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install the correct (MS VC++ 11) redistributable package?

Answer (score 12):

You will need to install the correct [Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) from Microsoft. Please note that you cannot just take any of those, you need to pick the one that goes with your very specific version of Visual Studio. The link for example is for VS 2012 SP1. If you have another version, you need another vcredist package.

Comment: MS updated recently the links to all older redists in a single page: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads

Answer (score 1):

Answer of user *nvoigt* seems to be correct (+1 for that). As an alternative to install Redist Package you can deploy "manually" MSVCP110.dll with your application. Easiest way is to put the dll where your exe is. But as the other people say: you need *the* correct version of redist pack which fits your system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This article https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/missing-msvcp110dll.html
pointed me in the right direction.  The file wasn't, however, in the directory they said it would be. So I did a search of hard drive for vcredist_x64.exe. It was buried deep in a directory for VisualStudio 12. When I reinstalled it the dll error disappeared and photoshop is running again.

I think I created the problem when I installed a newer version of Visual Studio.